# Why does my function using string interpolation give me two different errors based on the following code. Javascript

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation, function-call

I did figure out how to get the code to work properly by defining a separate local variable to store the returned functions value. I am just curious as to why using ${total} results in two different strings based on the following code.

**The following code interpolates the function body into the string.**

```
function placeOrder(cardNumber) {
  if (typeof cardNumber === 'undefined') {
    return "Sorry, we don't have a credit card on file for you."
  } else {
    let cartTotal = total();
    cart = []
    return `Your total cost is $${total}, which will be charged to the card ${cardNumber}.`
  }
}
```

**The following code interoplates the returned value of the total function and uses that value in the string it also throws a Type error that total is not a function**

```
function placeOrder(cardNumber) {
  if (typeof cardNumber === 'undefined') {
    return "Sorry, we don't have a credit card on file for you."
  } else {
    total = total();
    cart = []
    return `Your total cost is $${total}, which will be charged to the card ${cardNumber}.`
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is `total = total();`, which will not work the second time it is executed. This issue has nothing to do with the template string.

Comment: Thanks so much I just figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was overwriting the total() function with its returned value in the second example which allowed me to get the right answer 1 time. In the first code I did not overwrite the function and when I interpolated it I got the function body.